# High Power Battery System: Variable Input DC Voltage to Fixed AC Output Voltage

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, dc-ac

We are a team of students trying to build a battery system which would recreate wall socket conditions with up to 2 kW output.

Some of the main challenges are basically to have the battery's variable output voltage fixed at a certain value, let's say 24 V DC and then converted to 230 V AC.

In order to get a fixed voltage output at the battery (24 V), is the best option to use an isolated DC-DC converter? The problem is that with the powers involved (2 kW), we really are struggling to find off-the-shelf converters that would safely do the job. I guess we could get multiple smaller ones and connect them in parallel but then weight and volume become significant, is there any other method or is an Isolated DC-DC really the best solution?

The next step is to then convert this 24 V 2 kW output to 230 V AC, I guess here we have no choice but to find a suitable DC-AC converter or are there any other methods we could use?

Comment: http://everproject.blogspot.com/2012/09/2000-watt-inverter-circuit-diagram-24v.html -- https://www.instructables.com/id/250-to-5000-watts-PWM-DCAC-220V-Power-Inverter/

Comment: Why do you need to create a stable 24 volts and then convert again? Seems like pointless extra losses.

Comment: Because most DC-AC converters seem to only accept fixed voltage inputs and no variable ranges like that of a discharging battery.

Comment: For the DC-DC conversion, I cannot find any module able to provide more than 1000W. We will need 4000W at the output of the  DC-AC inverter.
In this case, would it be possible to use a 1000W DC-DC converter such as the: Meanwell SD-1000L-24 and connect the input of two of them in parallel at the output of a 2kW Li-ion module? Or is it better to just have 1kW Li-ion/DC-DC converter systems and then connect the output of those in parallel to power the DC-AC inverter?

Comment: You have to ensure the converters you purchase has a sync function.  This is required to parallel- or series- connect them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not need a DC-DC converter. I assume you are thinking of buying an inverter of the shelf, something like this,
https://www.banggood.com/Intelligent-Color-Screen-Pure-Sine-Wave-Power-Inverter-12V24V-To-220V-3000W4000W5000W-Converter-p-1243542.html?rmmds=search&ID=534726&cur_warehouse=CN

These inverters are supposed to go with lead-acid batteries either 12 V or 24 V, so it does not need the exact 12 V or 24 V it supports low voltage up to 10 V or 20 V as the battery voltage reduces when it discharges.

Comment: How does the inverter take a range of input voltage and normalize it to a consistent voltage?   Does it use a DC-DC converter?  Keeping in mind the OP wants to design the circuitry to do the same as what is inside that inverter.  Does the OP still not need a DC-DC converter?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that if you have a Li-ion battery with 4 cells in series. At max voltage you get 16.8V and 10V at minimum voltage. A 12V DC-AC converter will tolerate from 11V to 15V which leaves a big range of the stored energy out of what can be used by the inverter.